# laravel many-many relationship pivot data saving as null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship in my application that allows many users to be associated with many projects, and each of those associations can have a different role.

## Project.php

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

## User.php

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withPivot('role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I attach a user and their pivot data like so,

```
$project = Project::find($request->input('project_id'));
\DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log
$project->users()->attach($request->input('user_id', ['role' => $request->input('role')]));
dd(\DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log
```

However the outputted SQL,

```
insert into `project_user` (`created_at`, `project_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

There is no mention of the role column why is this, what have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `attach` call (parenthesis closed after role, role became the default value of user_id `$request->input($value, $default)`)

```
$project->users()->attach($request->input('user_id'), ['role' => $request->input('role')]);
```